# What is the difference between $.map and $.grep in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between `$.map` and `$.grep` in jQuery?

I want a simple answer as far as possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I will assume you mean `$.grep` and `$.map`.  The difference is that we use `$.grep` to filter an array while we use `$.map` to apply a function to each item in the array.

Here is a much better explanation than I can make:

http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-grep-and-map-example-and-syntax.html

Comment: the filter function could be the the function that we could apply in the `map` so we could use map or grep

Answer (score 12):

`$.map` method can be used as an iterator, but is meant to manipulate the array and return a new array.

```
var items = ['A','B','C','A'];    

var items = $.map(items, function(item) {
  if (item == 'A') 
    return null;
  return item;
});
```

items is now new array. `['B','C']`

or

```
var items = $.map(items, function(item) {
  if (item == 'A') 
    return 'A'+'B';
  return item;
});
```

output will be `['AB', 'B', 'C', 'AB']`

`$.grep` is used for filtering

```
var items = $.grep(items, function(item) {
      return item != 'A';
    });
```

items is now `['B','C']`

however

```
var items = $.grep(items, function(item) {
      if (item == 'A') 
        return 'A'+'B';
      return item;
    })
```

will return `['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']`
as it is not producing new stuff - it reduces the existing.