# Get Anchor Tag from textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea which contain list of link in the form of anchor tag and their inside content 
for e.g.

```
<a href="http://example1.com/azaz" class="tex1"> Example 1</a>
<a href="http://example1.com/aza" class="tex1"> Example 2</a>
<a href="http://example1.com/za" class="tex2"> Example 3</a>
<a href="http://example1.com/az" class="tex2"> Example 4</a>
```

Above information is given inside a textarea. I want after click submit i want to retrieve all anchor tag's href section of particular class like tex1.
for e.g. I want output like

> http://example1.com/azaz 
>  http://example1.com/aza

how can i achieve this Using Jquery/javascript

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var text = $("textarea").val();

var res = $(text).map(function() { 

       return $(this).attr("href");
});

console.log(res);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nwf4c077/6/)

Comment: As you are just filtering prefer $.grep. For difference between $.Map and $.Grep please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245140/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-grep-in-jquery